# Infinite Recursive Quicksort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to code a version of quicksort, but this just isn't working. When I run it, it first gives a stack overflow error, then just keeps sending access writing violations errors. Going through it manually and with a debugger revealed that it's just an infinite loop. In addition, the errors seem to be originating from the `swap` and `move` functions themselves (not me calling `swap`), but I haven't changed them at all.

```
int list[10];
int i;
int length = 10;

void quicksort(int thelist[], int first, int last)
{
    int lower = first + 1;
    int upper = last;
    swap(thelist[first], thelist[(first + last) / 2]);
    int pivot = thelist[first];
    while (lower <= upper)
    {
        while (thelist[lower] < pivot)
        {
            lower++;
        }
        while (pivot < thelist[upper])
        {
            upper--;
        }
        if (lower < upper)
        {
            swap(thelist[lower+1], thelist[upper-1]);
            lower++;
            upper--;
        }
        else
        {
            lower++;
        }
    }
    swap(thelist[upper], thelist[upper-1]);
    upper = upper - 1;
    if (first < upper - 1)
    {
        quicksort(thelist, first, upper - 1);
    }
    if (upper + 1 < last)
    {
        quicksort(thelist, upper + 1, last);
    }
    return;
}

void arrayout()
{
    cout << "Current array:";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    int h;
    for (h = 0; h < 10; h++)
    {
        cout << list[h];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void max_end(int thelist[], int n)
{
    int max;
    if(n < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    for(i = 1, max = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(thelist[max] < thelist[i])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    swap(thelist[n], thelist[max]);
    quicksort(thelist, 0, n-1);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to the quick sort." << endl << "First, I will generate a random series of 10 numbers from 1-100." << endl << "Generating..." << endl;
    int randnum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    randnum = rand() % 2;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        randnum = rand() % 100 + 1;
        rand();
        list[i] = randnum;
        randnum = rand() % 100 + 1;
        rand();
    }
    randnum = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << "Generated!" << endl << endl;
    arrayout();
    cout << "Sorting..." << endl << endl;
    clock_t start = clock();
    max_end(list, length - 1);
    clock_t end = clock();
    arrayout();
    double diff = end - start;
    double diffmilli = 1000 * diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Sorted!" << endl << "Time elapsed- " << diffmilli << " milliseconds." << endl << endl << "Just input something random once you're done."; >> endl;
    string nothing;
    cin >> nothing;
    return 0;
}
```

(Here are the swap/move functions, just in case it is buggy)

```
// TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Move
template<class _Ty> inline
    typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&
        _Move(_Ty&& _Arg)
    {   // forward _Arg as movable
    return ((typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&)_Arg);
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION swap (from <algorithm>)
template<class _Ty> inline
    void swap(_Ty& _Left, _Ty& _Right)
    {   // exchange values stored at _Left and _Right
    _Ty _Tmp = _Move(_Left);
    _Left = _Move(_Right);
    _Right = _Move(_Tmp);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your loops finding the next pair of elements run out of bounds eventually, causing you to `std::move()`/`std::swap()` memory you can't access: the error is **not** in these functions but in passing them junk arguments.

Comment: It's not an out of bound index error, it's a stack overflow, caused by infinite recursive call of the quicksort function. Whenever the infinite recursive call happens, the first and last differ in only one, and they stay the same until eternity. You can check it by printing first and last at the beginning of quicksort function. But even if you add something like:
`    if (first == last - 1)
    {
      if (thelist[first] > thelist[last])
        swap(thelist[first], thelist[last]);
      return;
    }
`
you'll see it doesn't fix your problem. You have serious indexing mistakes in you loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has multiple problems, I have given the list below

1. At while loop #1 lower <= upper, should be lower < upper, as we don't do any swapping when index are same (reason for your infinite loops(?))
2. Access out of array boundary at while loop #2 && #3 they should be "lower < upper && thelist[lower] < pivot" and "lower < upper && pivot < thelist[upper]"
3. At line "swap(thelist[upper], thelist[upper-1]);" you are attempting to swap your pivot back to its position (isn't your pivot at thelist[first] and not at thelist[upper], replace thelist[upper] with thelist[first])
4. Need to find where the pivot fits before swapping pivot hence add "if (pivot > thelist[upper]) upper++;" before swapping pivot
5. You could remove the else part of the last if statement within while loop #1 as it add no value

I think that should make your program work! I don't have Microsoft C++ to test that you are on your own on testing :(

Answer (score 0):

As already precised here, the problems aren't (obviously) in the `swap` and `move` functions, but, in some cases, in the ever recursive `quicksort` function and, in another ones, in the corrupting memory `quicksort` function. To detect when your indexes are getting out of range, you could use wrapper functions with `assert`, like this:

```
void safeSwap(int thelist[], const int first, const int last, const int lower, const int upper)
{
    assert(first <= lower);
    assert(first <= upper);
    assert(lower <= last);
    assert(upper <= last);

    swap(thelist[lower], thelist[upper]);
}

void safeQuicksort(int thelist[], const int first, const int last, const int lower, const int upper)
{
    assert(first <= lower);
    assert(first <= upper);
    assert(lower <= last);
    assert(upper <= last);

    quicksort(thelist, lower, upper);
}
```

**EDIT** The `quicksort` version that works:

```
void quicksort(int thelist[], const int first, const int last)
{
    //assert(first < last);
    if (last - first < 2)   //  avoid infinite recurrence 
    {
        if (thelist[first] > thelist[last])
            swap(thelist[first], thelist[last]);
        return;
    }

    int lower = first;
    int upper = last;
    //  choose the middle as pivot to avoid further swappings
    int pivot = thelist[(first + last) / 2];

    while (lower < upper)
    {
        while (thelist[lower] < pivot)
        {
            lower++;
        }
        while (pivot < thelist[upper])
        {
            upper--;
        }

        if (lower < upper)
        {
            swap(thelist[lower], thelist[upper]);
            lower++;
            upper--;
        }
    }

    if (first < upper)
    {
        quicksort(thelist, first, upper);
    }
    if (lower < last)
    {
        quicksort(thelist, lower, last);
    }
}

void max_end(int thelist[], int n)
{
    quicksort(thelist, 0, n);
}
```

I tried to keep your style (I don't use globals, arrays without size parameters) and your algorithm (I like the one iterator approach more: [In-place version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version)) as much as possible.

You can do as this to test it is really sorted:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; (i < 10) && (list[i] >= list[i-1]); i++);
assert(10 == i);
```

I did it for several special cases and in a huge loop (500 randoms: remember to call `srand` only once ;)!).